# httpd subdomain 404 error

Tags: apache, subdomain, vhosts

I have a working site at on the Top level of a domain, I now want to add a subdomain on the same domain and the same server.

The files for this site are located in the public html folder (/var/www/html)

I have the following virtualhosts/directory config in httpd.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin support.portal@somesite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/joomla3
    ServerName support.somesite.com
    ErrorLog logs/support.somesite.com_error.log
    CustomLog logs/support.somesite.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin support.portal@somesite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/moodle
    ServerName support.somesite.com/moodle
    ErrorLog logs/moodle.error.log
    CustomLog logs/moodle.access.log common
</VirtualHost>

<Directory "/var/www/html/moodle">
DirectoryIndex index.php
AcceptPathInfo on
AllowOverride None
Options None
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

No errors are reported on the start/restart of httpd

Nothing is reported in the httpd error log. The below entry is shown in the Access log so the request is reaching the webserver but appears to be not being handled properly by the webserver.

```
192.168.4.202 - - [05/Jan/2015:12:49:14 +0000] "GET /moodle HTTP/1.1" 404 290
```

I have configured something similar before but I can't figure out the problem here. I might have missed something obvious, Can you see where the problem is, Thanks?

I am running CentOS 6.5 for reference.

Comment: `ServerName support.somesite.com/moodle` won't work since `support.somesite.com/moodle` is not a domain name.

Comment: Hi, Sorry the 404 Issue was un-related to the webserver config.